# Updating a record via a action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

User signs up, is redirected to  a page to be collected info, pretty straight forward

I for my life can't figure out how to do this

My controller for the user

```
    def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     end

    def new
     @user = User.new
    end


   def additional_info
     #user = User.find session[:user_id]
     @user = User.update(user_addinfo)
     redirect_to user_path
   end


  def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
       #session[:user_id] = @user.id
       #UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
       sign_in @user
       redirect_to  additional_info_path
       flash[:success] = "Welcome to InYourShoes!"
      else
     render'new'
    end
  end
```

private

```
  def user_params 
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end


  def user_addinfo
    params.require(:user).permit(:year)
  end
 end
```

`user_addinfo` is the action method that i want to call updating my record on for my additional_info method.
the `def create` method has commented line that i'm unsure if necessary, particularly the `session[:user_id] = @user.id`. I was told that i need this in order to keep track of my session, but perhaps someone can debunk this for me, as im following michael hartl's tutorial.

as of right now with this code, rails is giving me a parameter missing in the 
`params.require(:user).permit(:year)` line.

Much help is greatly appreciated. Ive been trying many different things, and cant seem to figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller code as below:

```
   def additional_info
     @user = User.find params[:id]                        ## Set @user
   end

   def update
      if @user.update(user_addinfo)
           redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
      else
           render action: 'additional_info'
      end                  
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
       #session[:user_id] = @user.id
       #UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
       sign_in @user
       redirect_to  additional_info_path(@user)           ## Pass @user
       flash[:success] = "Welcome to InYourShoes!"
      else
       render'new'
      end
    end
```

and in your `routes.rb` update the `additional_info` route as

```
 get 'info/:id' => 'users#additional_info', :as => 'additional_info'
```

Comment: i need to render additional_info page.... its a form_for input. but thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Then in that case all you have to do is remove `redirect_to user_path(@user)` from `additional_info` action. So, once the action is completed your `additional_info view` would be rendered automatically as the route exists.

Comment: ok so it renders now, but how do i save the data from def additional_info into the data base? rails says there is no update method?

Comment: If you want to `update` the data from the additional_info page then add an `update` action in your controller. I hope you are not expecting me to write that.

Comment: no you just pointed me in the right direction! i thought rails has a built in method to update and save to the database? And once i save to the database, do i use uncomment redirect_to user_path(path) to go to the profile page?

Comment: `additional_info` action would render your `additional_info.html.erb` view and when you fill the form and submit `update` action would be called. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You `additional_info` action seems to be wrong. You need to pass in the id of the user for whom you are collecting additional information.

```
  def additional_info
     @user = User.find params[:id]
     @user.update_attributes(user_addinfo)
     redirect_to user_path(@user)
   end
```

Comment: error undefined local variable 'id' on this line
@user = User.find params[id]

Comment: Its `params[:id]` not `params[id]`

Comment: couldn't find a user without an id??

Answer (score 0):

The line you have commented in your create method:

```
 #session[:user_id] = @user.id
```

Is what is storing the user id to a session variable and not a param in the url.

You then have this line commented in your additional_info method

```
#user = User.find session[:user_id]
```

This is looking up the user by the id that you would have previously stored in the session variable.

At that point the user object would be stored in user
If you need it in your instance variable, make sure to modify the line to be

```
@user = User.find session[:user_id]
```

Your user would then be stored in @user and be able to be accessed in the view

Comment: so basically uncomment both of the comments?

Comment: You would need to do that if you are using a session to store where you are at.  You would probably need to comment out the next line @user = User.update(user_addinfo) as my guess is this view you are loading the user back in and then rendering the view.  Once you go through the tutorial , make sure to check out the devise gem for authentication as it is a complete solution

Comment: do i know to store the user id to a session variable? as far as i know, the session variable from the tutorial uses a token. I need @user= User.update(user_addinfo) because the page takes input data

Comment: I think you are missing a step.  Lets follow the code.  After you are creating the user, you are redirecting to additional_info.   At this point, you no longer have any params are record of what came from your form as you just came from a previous method. You now have to render the new view with your form and then post that form to to a user update method.

Comment: i need to clear some confusion. Is it required to store the user id to a session variable because the app doesn't know the state of the user?

Comment: Based on your last response, it seems like I dont need to store it?My logic is all im doing is calling the view that happens to have a form_for that will take input from the def user_addinfo action then post it into the database.